# Discord bot Interval confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a countdown timer sort of thing on my Discord bot.
Here is what I am using rn.

```
        //Command base
    client.on("message", async message => {

      var sender = message.author;

      const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      //timetestvars
      var starttimer = 0;
      var counter = 10;

        //countdown timer
          if (command === 'testcount'){
              while(starttimer <= 9){
                setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(counter), starttimer++, counter--},1*1)
              }

          };
});
```

but when I type in the command, nothing happens, like... nothing. The bot just crashes, I know I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong, how may I fix it and how does this code really work, and why is the conflict happening?

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Do you run your bot via node.js? If you do, have a look at the console, it will show the line which caused the error.

Comment: the bot functions perfect, it's just the timer command that does not work, I don't know what the error is, but the bot stops working once I use the command.

Comment: Yes, but do you use node js?????

Comment: Oh and I had a look into the link that you provided. You've probably mixed up some inverted commas in between.

Comment: Yes, bot uses Node.js, I will check in on that inverted comma thing and get back to you. Thanks for helping me btw.

Answer (score 0):

[`args.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) returns a number, so when you run `args.shift().toLowerCase()`, a `TypeError` is thrown.

Try using [`args.slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a new array of every element but the first.

In addition, `args.slice(1)` returns an array, which is not compatible with the .toLowerCase() method.

**Try replacing**

```
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

**With**

```
const command = args.slice(1)[0].toLowerCase();
```

---- or ----

```
const command = args[0].toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however, it does not seem like that line is the problem. I could send over the full .js doc over to you if you would like, just so you can see all of it and help me understand this problem.

Comment: args.shift() returns a number? Depends on contents of the array. That's not the problem I believe.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what I was thinking when I was writing this. I'll update the answer shortly, but I think the problem here is that the incrementor (starttimer++) is not being run inside the while loop due to it being inside the setTimeout function.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, but now there be a new problem. It only spits out 0's... and it doesnt wait, It just spits out hella 0s and stops and spits out more. (exactly 10, so I guess that part works). Thanks for helping me btw :)

Comment: Is that not the expected behavior? As of right now it is setting the timeout with a delay of 1 (meaning, the timeout will wait will wait 1 *ms* and then run the code. If you want it to count down, try using ‘starttimer * 1000’ instead of ‘1*1’

Answer (score 0):

The reason yours crashed is because the bot ran out of memory for trying to repeat the same thing so many times *before* `starttimer` even reached 9.

```js
while (starttimer <= 9) {
    setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(counter), starttimer++, counter--},1*1) // Note that setTimeout waits in milliseconds, not seconds (also 1*1=1) so the correct number to put here would be 1000
}
```

The correct way to do it  is like this:

```js
var starttimer = 10; // set this to your desired start time
for (let i=0; i <= starttimer; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        message.channel.send(i);
    }, 1000*(starttimer-i));
}
```

You can even get your start time by doing `var starttimer = args[0]` so the command you would use is `!testcount 10` (assuming you set your prefix to `!`) to start a 10 second timer for example. Note that if there is a delay it's because of the Discord API cooldown and there is not much workaround apart from setting the timer slower (by changing `1000*(starttimer-i)` to `2000*(starttimer-i)` for example).

P.S. I only just noticed that this question was asked over a year ago but I hope this helps somebody :P